# How to use Inspect Element in chrome via tablet (Android device)

Tags: android, android-layout, google-chrome-devtools, developer-tools

Is there any steps to navigate inspect element (Developer Console) in chrome via any of the android devices (tablet).

I tried using this [link](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/?utm_source=dcc&utm_medium=redirect&utm_campaign=2016q3#discover) but unable to connect my device to my desktop chrome browser. Is there any efficient way for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want to remote debug your Android tablet from a desktop / laptop? What OS is your desktop / laptop running?

Comment: @Kayce Basques I need to open developer console in chrome by using tablet. And I need to check that in my desktop ( windows 7 OS in my desktop).